# Need help populating an ASP.net gridview using JSON datasource in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

I have to create a gridview that is automatically populated with JSON.

I have created the JSON folder, it works fully, i can save data to it no problem.

The issue im having is now making my gridview in my ASP.net to automatically populate the form USING my JSON file.

I have tried using visual studios inbuilt LINQ wizard... It populated the headers of the gridview but not the fields itself.

Its a very simple gridview with 2 columns.

My current asp gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False
           " ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found" runat="server"  DataSourceID="Grid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="Grid" runat="server" ContextTypeName="BookCollection" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="id, Title" Select="new (id, Title)" TableName="Books">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

short sample of my JSON below (has one entry only atm, just showing the attributes)(Two total: id, and Title.)

```
{"Books":[{"id":1,"Title":"Harry Potter"}]}
```

My gridview does NOT load when opened in a browser, but I'm assuming this is because the datasource is not linked properly yet or have a page load function because i don't know what to do.

As you can tell i am very new to coding so sorry if i left anything out.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: please show us what you have tried to populate the GridView at server side

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by this?

Comment: I said i tried to use visual studios inbuilt data source with the config wizard LINQ option, then selected my JSON folder, and the correct headers were there, however the fields didnt populate.

Comment: Sorry, I expected to find data source being defined in the code behind but you have it into aspx page. That's also valid. The answers to the question are correct, just need code sample.

Answer (score 2):

I agree other answers on this page, just wanted to add code sample on how to achieve that. I'm removing DataSource from your aspx control as I will set it in code behind.

**Webform**

```asp
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True"
                   SortExpression="Title" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind**

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string jsonString = "{\"Books\":[{\"id\":1,\"Title\":\"Harry Potter\"}, {\"id\":2,\"Title\":\"Bible\"}]}";
    var json = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(BooksSource));
    GridView1.DataSource = ((BooksSource)json).Books;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Note: In your case you'll be reading json from a text file instead, with something like `File.ReadAllText(path);` or using streams if you work with large files.

**Data source classes**

```cs
public class BooksSource
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Joe, mark this as the answer. I've replied by phone and wasn't able to post the code! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that represent your json structure, like field names and data types, string, integer, etc.

Then in the page load event tead rhe json file, as you normally do with a text file.

Serialize the json string you have read to a list of classes previously created and assign it as datasource to the gridview.

Remove the linq datasource you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead of directly assigning your json data as the data source, you can instead create a new list or a datable, if you want a table like datatype. You can populate this new list or datatable with your json data and assign it as the GridView's datasource.

Depending on how big your json file is, this method should be work fine.

Comment: Sorry but it specifically has to use JSON.

Comment: I think in that case you can parse the json data and assign it to the GridView using Server side code(.aspx.cs file) rather than doing it in the aspx file. I haven't done this myself but I just googled it and found a lot of examples to do this.